# Crystal Reports 8.5 Concurrent Licenses Issue with vb6

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I'm having a licensing issue with my vb6 app and crystal reports 8.5. 
From time to time it keeps popping up saying

> "Not enough Concurrent Access Licenses
>   to log you on ..."

I've read some stuff online, saying I should close all instances of the report object and set all references to nothing when closing a report etc ...
That does not work.
Also, the application architecture does not use a crystal report server, all files used are distributed on the local machine.
Anything else I can do ?

Comment: Does this only happen after the application has been opened/used a while?  It sounds like the "stuff online" is correct and some process is hanging on to a license; are you sure there isn't a function somewhere that is exiting prematurely and not releasing a report object?  IIRC the crystal runtime has 5 concurrent licenses so it would take a while for all five to get hung up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting_/Crystal_Reports/Q_20707402.html) help?

Answer (score 2):

1) Make **absolutely** sure you are actually closing the report object. It's been a long time since I saw this error.
2) Load any report with the CROpenReportByTempCopy flag set, using the CRAXDRT.Application object's OpenReport method. Also make sure to set the Application object to Nothing as well.

Some code on how you're loading/using/closing the reports would be good...